# Can I access a file with a specific index or line number that I want to access?

Tags: java, file-read

I am having an issue with reading a file in java. the issue is I have one method "sender", that calls another method "getMessage". when I call getMessage I need to read from a file. each line of the file is a message. I need to open the file, get the message and return it back to sender. I have it finding the file, opening it and getting the first line, but the issue is every time I return the first message and try to come back for the second message, it reads the first line again. is there a way to specify I want the second line? or I could even keep track of the length of each message so I know the index of what character I want to start with but I don't know how to access the file with an index.

Answer (score 1):

> it reads the first line again. is there a way to specify I want the second line?

No; not unless you remember the position (in **bytes**, not characters and certainly not lines!) to start reading on. Files are bags o bytes, not 'sets of lines', the file system just doesn't work that way. The only way to 'navigate to the 814095th line' is to start reading from the top until you have read through 814095 newline symbols.

To access a file at some index, generally you'd use a `new RandomAccessFile`, but I doubt you really want this - why not just keep the InputStream open, inside a long-lived object, that has a 'getNextMessage' method that pulls exactly 1 line off every time you call it. `BufferedReader` is pretty much exactly this - already exists in java. Just use that.

Comment: thank you, since there was no specific way to achieve this i ended up just reading each line of the file into an array and using the array index to get the line I  wanted. thank you for your guidance.